# Wordpress 3.6 Remove trailing slash from index when in a subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For my website I decided to use wordpress to power my blog section.  I created a folder under my root directory of my site titled blog.  Now when I visit localhost/blog I get redirected to localhost/blog/ with the trailing slash.  How can I remove the trailing slash?

This is my wordpress .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```